# Powershell scripts manipulating desktop elements don't work with Scheduler

Tags: powershell, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have 2 scripts working, when I start them manually.

Moving mouse cursor out of Screen:

```
[system.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | out-null
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1999,100)
```

If there is a chrome browser open with title HUD, put it to kiosk mode:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")             
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Hud - Google Chrome")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")     
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F11}")
```

If I put them in a Scheduled Task on Windows 7 they don't work.

They work if I start a batch file calling the script file

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noninteractive -command "&C:\Users\Miniuser\Documents\chromeHUD.ps1"
```

But not if I start the batch file in a Scheduled Task.

It seems in a Scheduled Task I can't acces my UI elements.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using same user for executing the scheduled job and manually run the script?? Have you unchecked the 'hidden' option on task scheduler job ?

Comment: yes I am using the same user. And yes I tried both, checked and unchecked

Comment: If that is an option for you, better use AutoHotKey to automate GUI.

Answer (score 1):

When the script runs as a scheduled task, it runs in a different context/session and there is no GUI that it can "see", nor any way to interact with your existing session.

Answer (score 1):

As alroc answers, it does run under another context/session.

I was not able to find any workaround to get pass this... Using pure powershell... However i was able to get the job done with wscript.

in your PS script, open your chrome with this

```
    (new-object -com wscript.shell).run("http://localhost/",3)
```

It will open the default browser in full screen. i could use this with sendkeys in the task scheduler!

Answer (score 0):

To run a script as a scheduled task that must interact with the desktop
You have to create a folder (or two on a 64bit-windows):
(32Bit, always) C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
(64Bit) C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop